# Rcpp inline package error in compileCode

Tags: r, inline, rcpp

I have R installed along with these two packages Rcpp and inline. (I am doing a project that consists of speeding up a painfully slow program in R and I decided to use Rcpp)...I know I am doing something wrong...probably missing a step but i cannot figure it out. Props to Dirk if you're reading this! Thanks for Rcpp and the brand new inline package pdf but...it's still not running.
Please note that I'm a newbie. As stated before I cleaned out all other packages and only R is installed with Rcpp and inline (of course I have c++ installed as well).

```
    library(Rcpp)
    library(inline)
    x<-as.numeric(1:10)
    n<-as.integer(10)
    code<-"
    integer i 
    do 1 i=1, n(1)
    1 x(i)=x(i)**3
    "
    cubefn<-                       cfunction(signature(n="integer",x="numeric"),code,convention=".Fortran")
     ERROR(s) during compilation: source code errors or   compiler      configuration errors!
                Program source:
      1: #include <R.h>
      2: 
      3: 
      4: extern "C" {
      5:   void filef2424e34d61 ( int * n, double * x );
      6: }
      7: 
      8: void filef2424e34d61 ( int * n, double * x ) {
      9: 
     10: integer i
     11: do 1 i=1, n(1)
     12: 1 x(i)=x(i)**3
     13: 
     14: }
    Error in compileCode(f, code, language, verbose) : 
      Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created! 
    In addition: Warning message:
    running command 'C:/R/R-2.15.2/bin/x64/R CMD SHLIB filef2424e34d61.cpp 2> filef2424e34d61.cpp.err.txt' had status 1
```

If it is the construction of a package skeleton missing: i tried the simple rcpp_hello_world() example:

```
    rcpp_hello_world <- function(){

    .Call( "rcpp_hello_world", PACKAGE = "mypackage" )
    }

    Folder PATH listing for volume OS
    Volume serial number is 769C-A616
    C:.
```

The rest was a long list of odd symbols but what I could read was the name of c++ projects I have, I didn't include them as it would be too lengthy

```
    rcpp_hello_world <-function(){

    .Call("rcpp_hello_world",PACKAGE="mypackage")

    }

    rcpp_hello_world()

    Error in .Call("rcpp_hello_world", PACKAGE = "mypackage") : 
      "rcpp_hello_world" not available for .Call() for package "mypackage"
```

Anything would help please, also I have linux installed as well so if that is a better option please do tell. I am open to anything right now, the slightest progress makes is a delight

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually have a Fortran compiler installed?

If you don't, or you don't know, try your Linux box.  R on Windows *must* be able to compile source packages if you want to build with Rcpp and inline.  A good quick test is to try something like

```
R> myroot <- cppFunction('double myroot(double x) { return ::sqrt(x); }')
R> myroot(16)
[1] 4
R>
```

or equivalently via inline (where `rcpp` is a wrapper for the `cxxfunction(..., plugin="Rcpp")` call, you need the most recent inline package for that)

```
R> myroot2 <- rcpp(signature(xs="numeric"), 
+                  body='double x=as<double>(xs); return wrap(::sqrt(x));')
R> myroot2(16)
[1] 4
R>
```

If this does not work, read up on the R basics of installing Rtools for Windows etc. We have a few additional notes in the Rcpp FAQ as well.

Comment: The first piece of code runs perfectly, the second one doesn't. I get the same error as stated in the post. I am getting R set up in linux. Can I optimize a program using only cppFunction? If so then I guess it would do, but I figured inline would make things easier

Comment: What version of the inline package do you have?

Comment: I am currently using version 0.3.10 of the inline package on windows. I switched to linux where I installed the latest version of R, Rcpp and version 0.3.8-1 of inline package. I tried running your first example which worked well. The second one however gave me the error : Error: could not find function "rcpp", I remembered to call both libraries before writing any line of code. Is there any way to invoke SEXP in RcppFunction? if yes then I think I would be ok :)

Comment: `rcpp()` is a wrapper defined as `function(...) cxxfunction(...,plugin="Rcpp")` which was added recently. You should have it in 0.3.10.  And of course you can pass SEXP because that is all we can pass via `.Call()` :-)

Comment: It seems .call goes hand in hand with the inline package. However don't seem to be able to anything of the format src <- cxxfunction(signature()...) does it mean the inline package is not properly installed? Can I do something like x_<- 2 myroot <- cppFunction('double myroot(double x) { return ::SEXP x_ + x; }')

Comment: No, you just made that syntax up. You remain somewhat ignorant of the most basic examples and docs. We have eight vignettes and dozens of blog posts as well as examples on SO. Use those instead of guessing.