# Making nested for loops in R more efficient

Tags: r, nested-loops, equivalence

I am working on a research project where I want to determine equivalence of two distributions. I am currently using the Mann-Whitney Test for Equivalence and the code I am running (below) was provided with the book Testing Statistical Hypotheses of Equivalence and Noninferiority by Stefan Wellek (2010). Before running my data I am testing this code with random normal distributions which have the same mean and standard deviation. My problem is that there are three nested for loops and when running larger distributions sizes (as in the example below) the code takes forever to run. If I only had to run it once that would not be such a problem, but I am doing a simulation test and creating power curves so I need to run many iterations of this code (around 10,000). At the moment, depending on how I alter the distribution sizes, it takes days to run 10,000 iterations.

Any help in a way to increase the performance of this would be greatly appreciated.

```
x <- rnorm(n=125, m=3, sd=1)
y <- rnorm(n=500, m=3, sd=1)

alpha <- 0.05
m <- length(x)
n <- length(y)
eps1_ <- 0.2 #0.1382 default
eps2_ <- 0.2 #0.2602 default

eqctr <- 0.5 + (eps2_-eps1_)/2 
eqleng <- eps1_ + eps2_

wxy <- 0
pihxxy <- 0
pihxyy <- 0

for (i in 1:m)
 for (j in 1:n)
  wxy <- wxy + trunc(0.5*(sign(x[i] - y[j]) + 1))

for (i in 1:m)
 for (j1 in 1:(n-1))
  for (j2 in (j1+1):n)
    pihxyy <- pihxyy + trunc(0.5*(sign(x[i] - max(y[j1],y[j2])) + 1))

for (i1 in 1:(m-1))
 for (i2 in (i1+1):m)
  for (j in 1:n)
    pihxxy <- pihxxy + trunc(0.5*(sign(min(x[i1],x[i2]) - y[j]) + 1))

wxy <- wxy / (m*n)
pihxxy <- pihxxy*2 / (m*(m-1)*n)
pihxyy <- pihxyy*2 / (n*(n-1)*m)
sigmah <- sqrt((wxy-(m+n-1)*wxy**2+(m-1)*pihxxy+(n-1)*pihxyy)/(m*n))

crit <- sqrt(qchisq(alpha,1,(eqleng/2/sigmah)**2))

if (abs((wxy-eqctr)/sigmah) >= crit) rej <- 1
if (abs((wxy-eqctr)/sigmah) < crit)  rej <- 0

if (is.na(sigmah) || is.na(crit)) rej <- 1

MW_Decision <- rej

cat(" ALPHA =",alpha,"  M =",m,"  N =",n,"  EPS1_ =",eps1_,"  EPS2_ =",eps2_,
  "\n","WXY =",wxy,"  SIGMAH =",sigmah,"  CRIT =",crit,"  REJ=",MW_Decision)
```

Comment: Just to help us scope in, are there any lines in particular you can point out that you know take a long time?

Comment: Additionally, it's possible some of the `apply` functions may help. Perhaps wrapping your pihxyy expression in `lapply` or `sapply` may speed it up.

Comment: Could you just use the built in wilcox.test function?

Comment: The second two nested for loops are the problems...the first nested loop runs almost instantly. I have looked at the built in wilcox.test function, however, it is a classic hypothesis test and this implementation is for an equivalence test where the null and alternative hypotheses are switched. I have explored re-writing with lapply but I was unsuccessful as I have not used the apply family of functions much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**See edit below for an even better suggestion**

One simple suggestion to get a bit of a speed boost is to [byte compile](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/compiler/html/compile.html) your code.

For example, I wrapped your code into a function starting from the `alpha <- 0.05` line and ran it on my laptop. Simply byte compiling your current code, it runs twice as fast.

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- rnorm(n=125, m=3, sd=1)
y <- rnorm(n=500, m=3, sd=1)

# f1 <- function(x,y){ ...your code...}

system.time(f1(x, y))
#   user  system elapsed 
# 33.249   0.008  33.278 

library(compiler)
f2 <- cmpfun(f1)

system.time(f2(x, y))

#   user  system elapsed 
# 17.162   0.002  17.170
```

**EDIT**

I should add, this is the type of things that a different language would do much better than R. Have you looked at the [`Rcpp`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/index.html) and the [`inline`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/inline/index.html) packages?

I've been curious to learn how to use them so I figured this was a good chance.

Here's a tweak of your code using the `inline` package and Fortran (since I'm more comfortable with that than C). It wasn't hard at all (provided you know Fortran or C); I just followed the examples listed in [`cfunction`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/inline/docs/cfunction).

First, let's re-write your loops and compile them:

```
library(inline)

# Fortran code for first loop
loop1code <- "
   integer i,  j1,  j2
   real*8 tmp
   do i = 1, m
      do j1 = 1, n-1
         do j2 = j1+1, n
            tmp = x(i) - max(y(j1),y(j2))
            if (tmp > 0.) pihxyy = pihxyy + 1
         end do
      end do
   end do
"    
# Compile the code and turn loop into a function
loop1fun <- cfunction(sig = signature(x="numeric", y="numeric", pihxyy="integer", m="integer", n="integer"), dim=c("(m)", "(n)", "", "", ""), loop1code, language="F95")

# Fortran code for second loop
loop2code <- "
   integer i1, i2,  j
   real*8 tmp
   do i1 = 1, m-1
      do i2 = i1+1, m
         do j = 1, n
            tmp = min(x(i1), x(i2)) - y(j)
            if (tmp > 0.) pihxxy = pihxxy + 1
         end do
      end do
   end do
"    
# Compile the code and turn loop into a function
loop2fun <- cfunction(sig = signature(x="numeric", y="numeric", pihxxy="integer", m="integer", n="integer"), dim=c("(m)", "(n)", "", "", ""), loop2code, language="F95")
```

Now let's create a new function that uses these. So it's not too long, I'll just sketch the key parts I modified from your code:

```
f3 <- function(x, y){

  # ... code ...

# Remove old loop
## for (i in 1:m)
##  for (j1 in 1:(n-1))
##   for (j2 in (j1+1):n)
##     pihxyy <- pihxyy + trunc(0.5*(sign(x[i] - max(y[j1],y[j2])) + 1))

# Call new function from compiled code instead
pihxyy <- loop1fun(x, y, pihxyy, m, n)$pihxyy

# Remove second loop
## for (i1 in 1:(m-1))
##  for (i2 in (i1+1):m)
##   for (j in 1:n)
##     pihxxy <- pihxxy + trunc(0.5*(sign(min(x[i1],x[i2]) - y[j]) + 1))

# Call new compiled function for second loop
pihxxy <- loop2fun(x, y, pihxxy, m, n)$pihxxy

# ... code ...
}
```

And now we run it and voila, we get a *huge* speed boost! :)

```
system.time(f3(x, y))
#   user  system elapsed 
    0.12    0.00    0.12
```

I did check that it got the same results as your code, but you probably want to run some additional tests just in case.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion and the code! However, I am receiving an error when running the loop1fun and loop2fun lines to create those two functions. I am unfamiliar with Fortran and C (unfortunately) so I am having trouble debugging it. Below is the error I am getting:                                                                 Error in compileCode(f, code, language, verbose) : 
  Compilation ERROR, function(s)/method(s) not created!

Comment: Not exactly sure, they compiled fine for me. Those seem like errors of being able to compile the code, rather than the code itself. I tried googling "Error in compileCode" and there are several hits which could be useful. [Check that you have a Fortran compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939474/rcpp-inline-package-error-in-compilecode) or perhaps [that your `PATH` is correctly set up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23141982/inline-function-code-doesnt-compile).

Comment: Unrelated to your error, but I should also add that I don't know why I felt compelled to wrap _all_ of your code into a function. You can, of course, just replace the loops with (what I tentatively called) `loop1fun` and `loop2fun` without having everything else inside of a function (once you're hopefully able to compile them).

Comment: Something else that might help with your error. If you're on Windows, maybe check that you have [Rtools](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/installr/docs/install.Rtools) installed?

Comment: I installed Rtools as well as Rcpp which I had not installed (I only had inline) and everything is running perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 5):

You can use `outer` instead of the first double loop:

```
set.seed(42)

f1 <- function(x,y) {
 wxy <- 0
 for (i in 1:m)
  for (j in 1:n)
   wxy <- wxy + trunc(0.5*(sign(x[i] - y[j]) + 1))
 wxy
}

f2 <- function(x,y) sum(outer(x,y, function(x,y) trunc(0.5*(sign(x-y)+1))))

f1(x,y)
[1] 32041
f2(x,y)
[1] 32041
```

You get roughly 50x speedup:

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(x,y),f2(x,y))
Unit: milliseconds
     expr        min         lq     median         uq      max neval
 f1(x, y) 138.223841 142.586559 143.642650 145.754241 183.0024   100
 f2(x, y)   1.846927   2.194879   2.677827   3.141236  21.1463   100
```

The other loops are trickier.

Comment: Thank you for the help! That improves both the performance and simplicity of that loop!